# Unable to parse a date string of format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" into JODA LocalDateTime

Tags: java, swing, jodatime

I am not able to parse a date string of format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" into JODA LocalDateTime.

I am getting below exception:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "01/01/2017 00:30:00" is malformed at "/01/2017 00:30:00"**

Please help me to fix this error.

See below my code:

```
public void calculateTOUValues(Date startDate, Date eDate, ArrayList<Double> csvDataPerChannel) {

    DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    SimpleDateFormat format01 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String startDateString = format01.format(startDate) + " 00:30:00"; //concatenate 00:30:00
    String endDateString = format01.format(eDate) + " 00:00:00"; //concatenate 00:00:00

    LocalDateTime strDate = LocalDateTime.parse(startDateString); //exception encountered at this line of code
    LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(endDateString);
}
```

I am getting below exception on running this code:

> Output: { SEVERE: null java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   format: "01/01/2017 00:30:00" is malformed at "/01/2017 00:30:00"     at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:854)
>     at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:168)    at
>   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:157)     at
>   module1.TOUCalculatorCore.calculateTOUValues(TOUCalculatorCore.java:135)
>     at
>   module1.LaunchTOUCalcTool.submitButtonActionPerformed(LaunchTOUCalcTool.java:807)
>     at module1.LaunchTOUCalcTool.access$900(LaunchTOUCalcTool.java:32)
>     at
>   module1.LaunchTOUCalcTool$10.actionPerformed(LaunchTOUCalcTool.java:418)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) }

Comment: Please note that human beings only answer questions on stack overflow. Machines haven't become that intelligent yet.

Comment: Look at the exception - you don't have a space between the date and the time in the value it's trying to parse. That suggests your actual code isn't the same as the code you've shown. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, if you've already *got* a start date and end date, and just want `LocalDateTime` values, why are you formatting and parsing at all? You should avoid unnecessary string conversions.

Comment: Also, you're not even using `format1`, `format2` or `format3`...

Comment: Jon Skeet, I've copied the correct exception (includes space).

Comment: You are using `LocalDateTime.parse` without a specified format. That means it uses a default format that expects `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Your date string does not match this format.

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve] though, and you still haven't explained why you're formatting and parsing at all... you don't *inherently* have any string operations to perform, so why are you doing any?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem specifying the format. The below code worked, :)

```
    LocalDateTime strDate = LocalDateTime.parse(startDateString,
 DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(endDateString,
 DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Thanks @thomas Klager